# iterate using foreach loop with key=>value but assign different valirable to each lines output

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Is it possible to iterate using `foreach` loop with `key=>value` but assign different variable to each lines output. I am looking for something like this:

```
foreach($counts as $key => $value){
$c = $key . ' => ' . $value;
$d = $key . ' => ' . $value;
};
```

when the sample output from `vardump($counts)` looks like:

```
array(3) { ["Type_1"]=> int(1) ["Type_2"]=> int(3) ["Type_3"]=> int(1) }
```

Each
int() is a quantity so ideally I would like the output to look like

```
$c = 1
$d = 3
$e = 1
```

also ok with

```
$c = Type_1 1
$d = Type_2 3
$e = Type_3 1
```

Either way, I want to access the quantities by reference the variable directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use an array, that's what they are for:

```
foreach($counts as $key => $value){
    $output[] = $key . ' => ' . $value;
};
```

It depends on why you are doing this, how you will use it and what you know, but why not use the key:

```
foreach($counts as $key => $value){
    $output[$key] = $key . ' => ' . $value;
};
```

You could create an array of variable names and shift one off each time and use that, however you will never know how many there are and this is very bad practice:

```
$vars = range('a', 'z');

foreach($counts as $key => $value){
    ${array_shift($vars)} = $key . ' => ' . $value;
};
```

In your example you would have `$a`, `$b` and `$c`.

Comment: Thanks. it is coming in in an array and I was already using a `foreach` loop? What I am needing is to access the key later for each type so that I can cross reference it an compare it.

Comment: I don’t think your example what you want to do.  Maybe show exactly what you have and how you want to access it.

Comment: The example above is exactly what I have but doesnt work so I was trying to figure out a way to do it. I want to access each type individually so I can compare each type's quantity `["Type_1"]=> int(1)` such as 1 to something else. each `int(1)` or what ever is in the `int` is a quantity. I am trying to access each individually so I can compare quantities of each key with something else. That is why I am trying to set the variable for each . Hopefully that makes ense?

Comment: Just tried `$output[$key] = $key . ' => ' . $value;` which gave me - `string(12) "Type_3 => 1" `. Oddly enough that is the last `array(3) { ["Type_1"]=> int(1) ["Type_2"]=> int(3) ["Type_3"]=> int(1) } `. Not sure why it randomly chose the last one in the array?

Comment: Regardless of the variable you need to show what you are trying to do in a larger sense.  You want to loop and compare each quantity to something how and do what when you compare?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your purpose here but you can assign different variable to each lines output by using reference variable that stores the value of the $variable inside it, that is $key in your code like below. It will help in case you know what keys will be in counts array all the time.

```
$counts = [ "Type_1" => 1,"Type_2"=>3, "Type_3"=> 1 ];

foreach($counts as $key => $value){
  $$key = $key . ' => ' . $value;
};

echo $Type_1;
echo $Type_2;
echo $Type_3;
```

Output will be

```
Type_1 => 1
Type_2 => 3 
Type_3 => 1
```

Comment: Thanks. is there a dynamic way to do this? What I mean is instead of typing `echo Type_1` etc in case the name of `Type_1` changes in the db in the future so I dont have to hardcode this in the PHP? Or if a `Type_4` was added so I wouldnt have to modify the php if that makes sense?